# Reading source of strlen.c

Tags: apt, glibc

I am trying to download the source package that includes `strlen.c`. Which one should I be getting, and how?

I have tried looking at the different `glibc` / `eglibc`... variants but got confused as to which one to really get.

I am a beginner with `apt-cache` `apt-get` `aptitude` `dpkg` etc

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question well enough. `strlen.c` should be in the libc6 source package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt-get source libc6
nano eglibc*/string/strlen.c
```